# Getting a string from a map of a list of a list of strings

Tags: c++, string, list, dictionary

got a question on how to simplify some code in c++.

So we're given this lab in my CS course where we have to generate a large sentence based on an input file, storing the read lines in a map of a list of a list of strings (whew!). We have to search it using a recursive function.

So the map key is a string. The first list is a collection of lines, and the second list is a collection of strings that were parsed from the file.

```
map<string, list<list<string> > >
```

I need to get down to the list of strings to reconstruct it into one string. I've set up some iterators to get down to it but I'm getting a "segmentation fault 11" when it reaches my declaration of iterators.

"Grammar" is a map that has already been given input and is passed by reference.

"Incomplete" is a string equal to a key that is passed to the function.

Code snippet:

```
string found = "";
map<string, list<list<string> > >::iterator section = grammar.find(incomplete);
list<list<string> > listItem = section->second;
list<list<string> >::iterator lIt = listItem.begin();
srand(time(NULL));
++lIt;
advance (lIt, rand() % listItem.size());
list<string> stringItem = *lIt;
while (stringItem.empty() == false){
    found = found + " " + stringItem.front();
    stringItem.pop_front();
}
```

To explain the need of rand(): Our first list has multiple lists and we randomly choose one in order to generate the sentence. Have I used it correctly?

It stops about here. I'm sure there is a more simple way of getting down to that list but I can't seem to figure it out, and I'm guessing that I'm consuming a lot of memory to declare all these if "segmentation fault 11" is being thrown. Any suggestions?

Comment: Offhand, how is your list *loaded* and how is is assigned to the map that contains it (i.e from what source is the key that indexes the map sourced) ?

Comment: The program reads an external file that is formatted. There are several brackets ("{,}") that we read and store into the list. Each bracket can have several lines. Each bracket is given a "definition" where the first line has a word encased in a less-than and greater-than sign (like HTML). We store the definition as the key, then each line is broken into a list and all the lists are stored into the greater list and paired to the key.

Comment: The list<list<string> > was the professor's recommendation because we may deal with a very large file. I'm starting to think that it may be easier to use a vector of vectors. Not too sure though.

Answer (score 0):

There may be more problems, but here are two obvious ones:

1. You don't check whether `grammar.find(incomplete);` actually finds an element. If the search fails, it returns `grammar.end()` and the rest of your can just blow up.
2. There's a problem in how you try to find a random element:

`list<list<string> >::iterator lIt = listItem.begin();`

`*lIt` is now the first list in `listItem`.

`++lIt;`

`*lIt` is now the second list in `listItem`.

`advance (lIt, rand() % listItem.size());`

This may try to advance the iterator too far. If the size of your list is `n` you can advance at most `n-2` steps, otherwise you're overshooting the end. But `rand() % n` can be `n-1`.

Comment: Ok, I'll add in an if- statement to check if it exists. I'll also comment out the ++lIt;

Comment: @user1993468 You should also check that `listItem` is not empty before using it.

Comment: I'm combing through and checking that I'm storing data into listItem. I'll add another if- statment. Thanks!